# Aria-hidden="true" no me funciona

Tags: html5

Hola he estado intentando usar el aria-hidden para colocar unas barras que no se vean para el ordenador y luego darle estilos para que se visualicen en el celular pero al parecer el atributo no me funciona y se ve todo igual, que debo hacer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text">
    <label id="tp1-label" for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" size="20"
           aria-labelledby="tp1-label"
           aria-describedby="tp1"
           aria-required="true" />
    <div id="tp1" class="tooltip"
         role="tooltip"
         aria-hidden="true">El nombre es obligatorio</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

El aria-hidden me aparece igual en la pantalla

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código, checa [ask]

Comment: Acabo de agregar el código, no veo fallas en el código desde un principio, pero no me funciona para nada

Answer (score 2):

**aria-hidden** no hace que tu elemento desaparezca de la pantalla, lo que permite es que no sea reconocido por los interpretes que leen las paginas para personas con discapacidad visual.

Te adjunto un video para que veas su funcionamiento https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzEx-yljhPI

Si quieres que tu elemento desaparezca, puedes añadir las siguientes lineas en tu archivo css:

```
[aria-hidden="true"] { 
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Si quieres utilizar solo css, puedes utilizar media query para hacer aparecer y desaparecer tu elemento:

```
#nombre{
        display: none;
    }

    @media(max-width: 720px){
        #nombre{ 
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

Con el codigo anterior tu 'input' sera visible cuando tu pagina tenga width menor a 720px, a partir de mas de 720px tu 'input' sera invisible.